# Excel VBA - 2 cell values combined always equal 1

Tags: excel, vba

I have two cells with percentage values, those should always sum to 100%. I would like them to adjust automatically if one of the cells is adjusted. But I can only get it to adjust for one cell, I cant get it to adjust the other cell.

My first attempt was:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address ="$D$7" Then
    Range ("G7")="1-D7"
End If
End Sub
```

Works fine for change from D7 to G7, but the otherway around does not work. (I could change it to G7 but then I would have the same issue on D7)

My second attempt was:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Select Case Target.Address
    Case "$D$7":
        Range("G7") = "=1-D7"
    Case "$G$7":
        Range("D7") = "=1-G7"
End Select

End Sub
```

This would work, but I have the issue that the cases loop and thereby I lose the original value that I typed into D7 or G7.

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EnableEvents set to False disable invoking the sub while changing a cell on the sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
Select Case Target.Address
    Case "$D$7":
        Range("G7") = "=1-D7"
    Case "$G$7":
        Range("D7") = "=1-G7"
End Select
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

### A Worksheet Change: Two Cells Combined

- You need to disable events before writing to the same worksheet and reenable them afterwards.
- You don't want to disable events if there is no intersection i.e. if it's not one of the two cells that was changed.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(Me.Range("D7,G7"), Target)
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' it's not one of the cells; do nothing
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Select Case irg.Address(0, 0)
        Case "D7", "D7,G7"
            Me.Range("G7") = "=1-D7"
        Case "G7"
            Me.Range("D7") = "=1-G7"
    End Select

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```